# Are *.conf files with ~ ending (emacs backup files) interpreted?

Tags: linux, debian

Are configuration files with ~ ending (emacs backup files) interpreted when they are in conf.d directory ?

Comment: Which `conf.d` directory? Different programs have different rules. Most do skip common backup suffixes, but check their individual documentation.

Answer (score 0):

They should not be considered, but where to look for configuration files and their names is up to the individual program. Can't give general rules.